# How to call class member function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript, and I have defined class like the following way-

```
function ClassName()
{
  //Some code here
}

ClassName.prototype.memberFun = function(){
  alert("I'm in memberFun()");
}

ClassName.prototype.memberFun1 = function(){
  alert("I'm in memberFun1()");
  //Trying to call above function like
  this.memberFun();
}
```

Now, I am creating the object and calling the function here-

```
var ob = new ClassName();
ob.memberFun1();
```

But it is not working. I am getting an error saying-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'memberFun'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your code should work. There is nothing wrong with it. When I paste it in the the Chrome console I get your two alerts. What is not working?

Comment: Yah in my case its working what i have suggested

Comment: I am getting error Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'memberFun'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript does not have a variable type like `ClassName` in java... all [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables) are declared using [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

```
var ob = new ClassName();
ob.memberFun1()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eu7yk/)

Comment: Ohh.. srry I was using that only..just typing mistake..but it's not working

Comment: @CodeCrypt otherwise it is working fine... see the added fiddle... if you look at the browser console it is printing both the messages

Answer (score 0):

dont use `ClassName` instead

```
var ob = new ClassName();
ob.memberFun1();
```

See this [mozilla tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)